# Is is true that $\cos{x}*\sin{x} \le x \le \tan{x} \rightarrow{} \cos{x} \le \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \le \frac{1}{\cos{x}}$

Tags: calculus

Is is true that (for $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$) $$\cos{x}\sin{x} \le x \le \tan{x} \rightarrow{} \cos{x} \le \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \le \frac{1}{\cos{x}}$$
It seems like we are able to reach the conclusion from this inequality:

$$\cos{x}\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \le 1 \le \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \frac{1}{\cos{x}}$$ because we have $$\cos{x} \le \frac{\sin{x}}{x}$$  AND $$\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \le \frac{1}{\cos{x}}$$ Somehow the conclusion just does not sit right, but I cannot seem to articulate why or why not.

Comment: All three are equal at $x=0$. If you look at how they increase over time you will see that the they increase by their derivatives which are $\cos(2x)\leq1\leq\frac{1}{\cos(x)^2}$. Are you having issues with the inequality and sinc function?

Comment: @KitterCatter the problem is that $\frac{sin{x}}{x}$ is in two places at the same time but scaled by the respective other terms. I am trying to show it more explicitly algebraically. I think if I divide through and then multiply through by $\cos{x}$ it can become more clear.

Comment: Is your problem that you are assuming that $\cos x \sin x \le x\le\tan x$ is true and you are trying to prove $\cos x\le\frac{\sin x}{x}\le \frac{1}{\cos x}$ from it?

Answer (score 2):

The question asks if

$$\cos{x}\sin{x} \le x \le \tan{x} \implies \cos{x} \le \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \le \frac{1}{\cos{x}}$$

is true for $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. If we divide by $\sin x$ then

$$\cos{x} \le \frac{x}{\sin x} \le \frac{1}{\cos{x}} \implies \frac {\cos{x}}{1} \le \frac{x}{\sin x}\implies \cos x  \sin x \le x \implies \frac{\sin x}{x} \le \frac{1}{\cos x}$$

where the third inequality follows since $x,1,\cos x, \sin x$ are all positive. 
This satisfies both inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

We can graphically visualize it holds for all $x∈(0,π/2)$.

$(y=sinx*cosx)$ would be a downward parabolic function in the given interval with some co-ordinates as ${(0,0)} , {(0.865,0.5)} , {(1.73,0)}$. Whereas $y=x $ would correspond to $ {(0,0)},{(0.865,0.865)},{(1.73,1.73)}$ which is surely greater $>$ than $sinx*cosx$. Similarly for $tanx$ the co-ordinates would be $ {(0,0)},{(0.865,1)},{(1.73,\infty)}$ which is again $>$ than $y=x$ line. And we can clearly state that $sinx*cosx$ is a increasing in $(0,π/4)$ and decreasing in $(π/4,π/2)$ whereas $y=x$ and $y=tanx$ are strictly increasing functions in $x∈(0,π/2)$. So the result should follow.